# JS HTML Object, search for elements who's classes contain

Tags: javascript, json

I'm generating some HTML from JSON, which leaves me with an HTML object with a dynamic amount of children, depends on one the user and if they change the JSON.

I need to keep a reference to certain elements depending on the classes, so the user may change the name of the classes, but they will need to have certain keywords, so, for example, I want to keep a reference to `marvLightbox__close`.

Someone could change this to something like `something__close`, so how can I search this HTML object's children for just `close`?

I have not yet appended this object to the DOM, it's just in memory.

P.S. NO JQUERY!

**Edit**
Found out I can use this, but I feel like it's cheating a bit! Plus I need to support IE8...

```
document.querySelectorAll('[class*=-img]')
```

**Edit 2**

The Polyfill actually isn't too many lines, so it's not too bad after all...

```
if (!document.querySelectorAll) {
  document.querySelectorAll = function (selectors) {
    var style = document.createElement('style'), elements = [], element;
    document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(style);
    document._qsa = [];

    style.styleSheet.cssText = selectors + '{x-qsa:expression(document._qsa && document._qsa.push(this))}';
    window.scrollBy(0, 0);
    style.parentNode.removeChild(style);

    while (document._qsa.length) {
      element = document._qsa.shift();
      element.style.removeAttribute('x-qsa');
      elements.push(element);
    }
    document._qsa = null;
    return elements;
  };
}
```

Comment: Well I was going to try querySelectorAll but not too sure how to use this for this use? P.S. If you downvote, leave a comment and explain why, otherwise it's pointless.

Comment: Wasn't me that downvoted.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll this one supports IE8

Comment: @freginold don't worry I didn't think it was, that was too who ever it was :D

Answer (score 0):

Found out I can use this, but I feel like it's cheating a bit! Plus I need to support IE8...

```
document.querySelectorAll('[class*=-img]')
```

The Polyfill actually isn't too many lines, so it's not too bad after all...

```
if (!document.querySelectorAll) {
  document.querySelectorAll = function (selectors) {
    var style = document.createElement('style'), elements = [], element;
    document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(style);
    document._qsa = [];

    style.styleSheet.cssText = selectors + '{x-qsa:expression(document._qsa && document._qsa.push(this))}';
    window.scrollBy(0, 0);
    style.parentNode.removeChild(style);

    while (document._qsa.length) {
      element = document._qsa.shift();
      element.style.removeAttribute('x-qsa');
      elements.push(element);
    }
    document._qsa = null;
    return elements;
  };
}
```